# Verificar Datos

Tags: java

estoy bloqueada y no sé como seguir adelante.

Tengo los siguientes datos:

```
String Equiv1="";
    String Equiv2="";
    String equivalencia1="";

public int probarEquiv1 (){
    Equiv1 =ConversorNou.PrimeraDivisaTXT.getText();
    Equiv2 = ConversorNou.SegundaDivisaTXT.getText();
    equivalencia1 = ConversorNou.EquivalenciaTXT.getText();
```

Y tengo que verificarlos uno a uno.

Es decir :

1- Verificar que Equiv1 sea "Dolar", "Euro", "peso" si es correcto que pase a la siguiente verificación.

2- Verificar Equiv2: Sea "dolar", Euro, Peso pero que no se repita con Equiv1 ( es decir si Equiv1 es Dolar entonces Equiv2 solo podrá ser Peso o Euro )
Si es correcto pasará a verificar lo siguiente.

3-Verificar que es Equivalencia que tiene que ser:  Numero mayor de 0, y puede aceptar decimales.

Cual es mi problema que sé verificarlos todos juntos pero no por separado.

Al final si la verificación de todo es correcto tienen que irse a RETURN 1 si es incorrecto a RETURN 2 ( pero si sale la opción return 2 que es incorrecto tengo que saber que parte de la verificación es incorrecta )

El problema que tengo es que no sé como hacer las verificaciones una a una y hacer que el return muestre cual es el dato erroneo.

Si da error cualquiera de las 3 verificaciones tengo que saber 100% cual de ellas es y mostrarla con el setFocus()

La parte de los return es esta:

```
Button botonDadesEntrades = new Button(Conversor_de_divises, SWT.BORDER);
        botonDadesEntrades.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            if (data.probarEquiv1()==1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos Correctos");


            }else{
                 PrimeraDivisaTXT.setFocus(); // asigno el foco al textfield 
                 PrimeraDivisaTXT.selectAll(); // luego selecciono todo el texto 

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error has puesto un dato incorrecto "

            }

            }
        });
```

Necesito saber como modificar la parte de return 2 para que muestre cual es el dato incorrecto.

gracias de anticipado! Se trata de usar los setfocus() setall() para seleccionar el incorrecto. Pero estoy bloqueada.. T_T

gracias!

Editado:

La parte probar Equiv1 que he hecho:

```
if(Equiv1.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro")&& Equiv2.equalsIgnoreCase("Dolar")&& DatosUser.esDecimal1(equivalencia1)){
        return 1;
    }
    else if ( Equiv1.equalsIgnoreCase("Dolar")&& Equiv2.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro")&& DatosUser.isNumeric(equivalencia1)){
    return 1;               
    }
    else if ( Equiv1.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro")&& Equiv2.equalsIgnoreCase("Dolar")&& DatosUser.isNumeric(equivalencia1)){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (Equiv1.equalsIgnoreCase("Dolar")&& Equiv2.equalsIgnoreCase("Euro")&& DatosUser.esDecimal1(equivalencia1)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}

     private static boolean isNumeric(String cadena){
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(cadena);
                return true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                return false;
            }}


     public static boolean esDecimal1(String cad)
     {
     boolean hayPunto=false;
     StringBuffer parteEntera = new StringBuffer();
     StringBuffer parteDecimal = new StringBuffer();
     int i=0, posicionDelPunto;

     for( i=0;i<cad.length(); i++ )
     if ( cad.charAt(i) == '.')                          //Detectar si hay un punto decimal en la cadena
     hayPunto=true;
     if(hayPunto)                                            //Si hay punto guardar la posicion donde se encuentra el carater punto
     posicionDelPunto=cad.indexOf('.');                  //(si la cadena tiene varios puntos, detecta donde esta el primero).
     else
     return false;                                       //Si no hay punto; no es decimal

     if( posicionDelPunto == cad.length()-1 || posicionDelPunto== 0)    //Si el punto esta al final o al principio no es un decimal
     return false;

     for( i=0;i<posicionDelPunto; i++ )
     parteEntera.append(cad.charAt(i)) ;                 //Guardar la parte entera en una variable

     for(i = 0; i<parteEntera.length(); i++)
     if( ! Character.isDigit(parteEntera.charAt(i)) )    //Si alguno de los caracteres de la parte entera no son digitos no es decimal
     return false;

     for( i=posicionDelPunto+1;i<cad.length(); i++ )
     parteDecimal.append(cad.charAt(i));                 //Guardar la parte decimal en una variable

     for(i = 0; i<parteDecimal.length(); i++)
     if( ! Character.isDigit(parteDecimal.charAt(i)) )   //Si alguno de los caracteres de la parte decimal no es un digito no es decimal
     return false;                                   //Incluye el caso en el que la cadena tenga dos o mas puntos

     return true;                                            //Si paso todas las pruebas anteriores, la cadena es un Numero decimal
     }


     public boolean esDecimal(String cad)
     {
     try
     {
       Double.parseDouble(cad);
       return true;
     }
     catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
     {
       return false;
     }




    }
}
```

Comment: la funcion probarEquiv1 esta incompleta. completala para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: La función probarEquiv1 tiene que retornar un valor de retorno distinto, para cada uno de los posibles errores que deseas validar. Edita tu pregunta para colocar la función completa, así podremos ayudarte.

Comment: ya esta añadido pero como he dicho esta incorrecto por que lo he verificado todo.. T_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tambien te adjunto aquí otra manera de ver el tema, realizas la validacion de todos los atributos que quieras y generas una lista de errores, es decir la validación se hace siempre a todos los atributos y luego se genera una lista de errores y un estado de la validacion que solo sera *OK* si no hay ningun error, te paso el código:

```
public class Validador {
  private static final String EURO = "Euro";
  private static final String DOLAR = "Dolar";
  private static final String PESO = "Peso";

  public Resultado procesa(String tipoMoneda1, String tipoMoneda2,
        String equivalencia) {
    Resultado resultado = new Resultado();
    if (!validaTipoMoneda(tipoMoneda1)) {
        resultado.setEstado(Resultado.KO);
        resultado.addError("tipo de moneda 1 no valida");
    }
    if (!validaTipoMoneda(tipoMoneda2)) {
        resultado.setEstado(Resultado.KO);
        resultado.addError("tipo de moneda 2 no valida");
    }
    if (sonMismoTipoMoneda(tipoMoneda1, tipoMoneda2)) {
        resultado.setEstado(Resultado.KO);
        resultado.addError("tipo de moneda 1 y tipo de moneda 2 son iguales");
    }
    try {
        double equivalenciaConvertida = convierteEquivalencia(equivalencia);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
        resultado.setEstado(Resultado.KO);
        resultado.addError("Equivalencia no es convertible a valor numerico");
        return resultado;
    }
    return resultado;
  }

  private boolean validaTipoMoneda(String tipoMoneda) {
    return tipoMoneda.equalsIgnoreCase(EURO)
            || tipoMoneda.equalsIgnoreCase(DOLAR)
            || tipoMoneda.equalsIgnoreCase(PESO) ? true : false;
  }

  private boolean sonMismoTipoMoneda(String tipoMoneda1, String tipoMoneda2) {
    return tipoMoneda1.equalsIgnoreCase(tipoMoneda2) ? true : false;
  }

  private double convierteEquivalencia(String equivalencia) {
    return Double.valueOf(equivalencia);
  }

  class Resultado {
    public static final boolean OK=true;
    public static final boolean KO=false;
    private boolean estado;
    private List<String> errores;

    public Resultado() {
        this.estado=OK;
        this.errores=new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public boolean isEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(boolean estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public List<String> getErrores() {
        return errores;
    }

    public void setErrores(List<String> errores) {
        this.errores = errores;
    }

    public void addError(String error) {
        errores.add(error);
    }

  }

}
```

Sus test para verificar comportamiento correcto:

```
public class ValidadorTest {

  @Test
  public void testValida_moneda1_no_valida() {
    Validador validador = new Validador();
    Resultado res = validador.procesa("Rupia", "Dolar", "1.23");
    assertThat(res.isEstado(), is(equalTo(Resultado.KO)));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().size(),is(1));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().get(0),is(equalTo("tipo de moneda 1 no valida")));
  }

  @Test
  public void testValida_moneda2_no_valida() {
    Validador validador = new Validador();
    Resultado res = validador.procesa("Dolar", "Rupia", "1.23");
    assertThat(res.isEstado(), is(equalTo(Resultado.KO)));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().size(),is(1));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().get(0),is(equalTo("tipo de moneda 2 no valida")));
  }

  @Test
  public void testValida_monedas_son_iguales() {
    Validador validador = new Validador();
    Resultado res = validador.procesa("Dolar", "Dolar", "1.23");
    assertThat(res.isEstado(), is(equalTo(Resultado.KO)));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().size(),is(1));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().get(0),is(equalTo("tipo de moneda 1 y tipo de moneda 2 son iguales")));
  }

  @Test
  public void testValida_equivalencia_no_convertible() {
    Validador validador = new Validador();
    Resultado res = validador.procesa("Dolar", "Euro", "23#2");
    assertThat(res.isEstado(), is(equalTo(Resultado.KO)));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().size(),is(1));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().get(0),is(equalTo("Equivalencia no es convertible a valor numerico")));
  }

  @Test
  public void testValida_ok() {
    Validador validador = new Validador();
    Resultado res = validador.procesa("Dolar", "Euro", "1.17");
    assertThat(res.isEstado(), is(equalTo(Resultado.OK)));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().size(),is(0));
  }

  @Test
  public void testValida_listaErrores() {
    Validador validador = new Validador();
    Resultado res = validador.procesa("Rupia", "Rupia", "23#4");
    assertThat(res.isEstado(), is(equalTo(Resultado.KO)));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().size(),is(4));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().get(0),is(equalTo("tipo de moneda 1 no valida")));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().get(1),is(equalTo("tipo de moneda 2 no valida")));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().get(2),is(equalTo("tipo de moneda 1 y tipo de moneda 2 son iguales")));
    assertThat(res.getErrores().get(3),is(equalTo("Equivalencia no es convertible a valor numerico")));
  }

}
```

Comment: no conocía  assertThat

Gracias de verdad!

Answer (score 2):

Te adjunto un código para resolver tu problema, las validaciones están en métodos privados y para formar los que tu llamas *RETURN* he creado la clase **Resultado** que almacena los resultado de validación, puedes modificarla a tu gusto:

```
public class Validador {
  private static final String EURO = "Euro";
  private static final String DOLAR = "Dolar";
  private static final String PESO = "Peso";

  public Resultado procesa(String tipoMoneda1, String tipoMoneda2, String equivalencia) {
    Resultado resultado = new Resultado();
    if (validaTipoMoneda(tipoMoneda1)) {
        if (validaTipoMoneda(tipoMoneda2)) {
            if (!sonMismoTipoMoneda(tipoMoneda1, tipoMoneda2)) {
                try {
                    double equivalenciaConvertida = convierteEquivalencia(equivalencia);
                    resultado.setTipoReturn("RETURN1");
                    resultado.setErrorValidacion("no existen errores");
                } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
                    resultado.setTipoReturn("RETURN2");
                    resultado.setErrorValidacion("Equivalencia no es convertible a valor numerico");
                    return resultado;
                }
            } else {
                resultado.setTipoReturn("RETURN2");
                resultado.setErrorValidacion("tipo de moneda 1 y tipo de moneda 2 son iguales");
            }
        } else {
            resultado.setTipoReturn("RETURN2");
            resultado.setErrorValidacion("tipo de moneda 2 no valida");
        }
    } else {
        resultado.setTipoReturn("RETURN2");
        resultado.setErrorValidacion("tipo de moneda 1 no valida");
    }
    return resultado;
  }

  private boolean validaTipoMoneda(String tipoMoneda) {
    return tipoMoneda.equalsIgnoreCase(EURO) || tipoMoneda.equalsIgnoreCase(DOLAR)
            || tipoMoneda.equalsIgnoreCase(PESO) ? true : false;
  }

  private boolean sonMismoTipoMoneda(String tipoMoneda1, String tipoMoneda2) {
    return tipoMoneda1.equalsIgnoreCase(tipoMoneda2) ? true : false;
  }

  private double convierteEquivalencia(String equivalencia) {
    return Double.valueOf(equivalencia);
  }

  class Resultado {
    private String tipoReturn;
    private String errorValidacion;

    public String getTipoReturn() {
        return tipoReturn;
    }

    public void setTipoReturn(String tipoReturn) {
        this.tipoReturn = tipoReturn;
    }

    public String getErrorValidacion() {
        return errorValidacion;
    }

    public void setErrorValidacion(String errorValidacion) {
        this.errorValidacion = errorValidacion;
    }

  }

}
```

Sus test para verificar el comportamiento esperado:

```
public class ValidadorTest {

  @Test
  public void testValida_moneda1_no_valida() {
    Validador validador = new Validador();
    Resultado res = validador.procesa("Rupia", "Dolar", "1.23");
    assertThat(res.getTipoReturn(), is(equalTo("RETURN2")));
    assertThat(res.getErrorValidacion(), is(equalTo("tipo de moneda 1 no valida")));
  }

  @Test
  public void testValida_moneda2_no_valida() {
    Validador validador = new Validador();
    Resultado res = validador.procesa("Dolar", "Rupia", "1.23");
    assertThat(res.getTipoReturn(), is(equalTo("RETURN2")));
    assertThat(res.getErrorValidacion(), is(equalTo("tipo de moneda 2 no valida")));
  }

  @Test
  public void testValida_monedas_son_iguales() {
    Validador validador = new Validador();
    Resultado res = validador.procesa("Dolar", "Dolar", "1.23");
    assertThat(res.getTipoReturn(), is(equalTo("RETURN2")));
    assertThat(res.getErrorValidacion(), is(equalTo("tipo de moneda 1 y tipo de moneda 2 son iguales")));
  }

  @Test
  public void testValida_equivalencia_no_convertible() {
    Validador validador = new Validador();
    Resultado res = validador.procesa("Dolar", "Euro", "23#2");
    assertThat(res.getTipoReturn(), is(equalTo("RETURN2")));
    assertThat(res.getErrorValidacion(), is(equalTo("Equivalencia no es convertible a valor numerico")));
  }

  @Test
  public void testValida_ok() {
    Validador validador = new Validador();
    Resultado res = validador.procesa("Dolar", "Euro", "1.17");
    assertThat(res.getTipoReturn(), is(equalTo("RETURN1")));
    assertThat(res.getErrorValidacion(), is(equalTo("no existen errores")));
  }

}
```

Espero que te ayude ;)